# Multiproject build: dependency to tests jar

Tags: java, gradle

I'm restructuring/refactoring build process for a big(ish) project. Currently it contains over a dozen separate modules built with standalone build scripts each. I want to integrate them all into a single multiproject build in Gradle.

After I integrated all sources into a single tree, fixed `build.gradle`s, I came upon the following problem. Dependencies for many modules contain something like:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.company', name: 'Module', version: '1.2.3'
    // ...
    testCompile group: 'com.company', name: 'Module', version: '1.2.3', classifier: 'tests'
}
```

I want the build to use jars from the subproject, not from a repository. I replaced `compile ...` with `compile project(':Module')` and it works fine. However, I cannot find the way to pass 'tests' specifier to the `testCompile project...` dependency.

Is there a way to pick up the `tests` jar as a dependency to `testCompile`?

Comment: Wait ... Do you have test code in project A that depends on test code in project B? That sounds a bit unusual. Assuming that we're talking about unit tests, they would normally be highly local.

Comment: Well... Yes. I inherited a project in a really sorry state. Project B has some test utilities that unit tests in Project A depend on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the producing project you will need to declare the "Test" JAR as outgoing artifact.

```
configurations {
    testUtils
}

task testUtilsJar(type: Jar) {
    ...
}

artifacts {
    testUtils testUtilsJar
}
```

In the consuming project you depend on it as such:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile project(path: ':Module', configuration: 'testUtils')
}
```